# Flex 4 <mx:Component> could not resolve

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex3

I am using flash builder 4 to run sample application from "Getting Started with FLEX 3", but the code can't run because there is one place that FB4 can't resolve, I guess this is because the library has been obsolete but after a tons of search I can't find the solution.

Thanks.
Bin

Comment: Post the code - `<mx:Component>` cannot be put anywhere in the mxml - there are some rules governing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Flex4 you'll want fx:Component instead